# Where does the centripetal come from, in a cyclone?

Tags: pressure, atmospheric-science, centripetal-force, coriolis-effect, weather

It needs a tremendous amount of impulse ($Force\times time$) to keep the large mass of air and water vapor spinning for several days. Where does the sustained force come from?
The centripetal force in this case is horizontal, so I don't think it would come from buoyancy

Comment: That is why meteorologists care so much about pressure gradients. http://www.hurricanescience.org/science/science/primarycirculation/

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the fact that a region of low pressure is surrounded by a region of high pressure, so the air all wants to move inward. This is in fact what creates the cyclone in the first place. As the air rushes towards the center, any slight rotation in the system gets amplified as the radius decreases – like the clichéd yet informative example of a figure skater pulling his arms inward.

Comment: Thanks. This explains most of it. I wonder where the angular momentum to spin tonnes of air at a hundred km/h come from.